# Setup X1-Xn and Y for LinearRegression with Spark DataSet

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am pretty new to Spark and have just created my first DataSet which looks like this by using `dataSet.show()`
.

```
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+--------------------+
|            D_5|             D_10|                 D_15|               D_20|                 D_25|              D_30|              D_60|                PSA_7|            PSA_14|            PSA_21|         W_12_26|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+--------------------+
|-0.00152148003689...|-0.00342246005311...|-0.00347943999804...|-0.00395856983959...|-0.00547327985987...|-0.00565074989572...|0.002974709961563...| 33.77974319458008|38.598060607910156|  42.5314826965332|-8.02228227257728...|
|-0.00160289998166...|-0.00392246991395...|-0.00372234010137...|-0.00402763020247221|-0.00600928021594882|-0.00546786980703...|0.002180940005928278|28.732168197631836|35.798316955566406| 40.34490966796875|-8.85122804902494E-4|
|-6.48349989205598...|-0.00309228990226...|-0.00539349997416...|-0.00408020010218...|-0.00505394022911787|-0.00536157982423...|0.002037039957940...|28.362024307250977|35.590187072753906| 40.18252944946289|-9.43946477491408...|
```

From my knowledge some years ago from university all columns except `W_12_26` are my xIn values and `W_12_26|` itself is my yIn.

By checking the [docu](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/ml-classification-regression.html#linear-regression) I am a bit confused by setting up my columns xIn and yIn to build this model and a predictor?

I would appreciate a lot bringing me on track here.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use a pipeline. This gives a lot of flexibility. Refer below example :

```
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline,PipelineModel
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler,MinMaxScaler
from pyspark.sql.types import *
# Test data
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)],schema=["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","label"])
# assemble all the input features as a single vector
vecAssembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=[x for x in df.columns if x not in 'label'], outputCol="features",handleInvalid='skip')
# scale all the inputs in a given range - optional
normalizer = MinMaxScaler(inputCol="features", outputCol="scaledFeatures",min=0,max=1)
# define the classifier as needed
classifier = LogisticRegression(featuresCol='features', labelCol='label', predictionCol='prediction', maxIter=40)
# Create a pipeline with the needed stages
pipeline_test = Pipeline(stages=[vecAssembler,normalizer,classifier])

# train the model - This can be saved and loaded
pipeline_trained = pipeline_test.fit(df) # split the data here and use train set
# prediction - this gives a dataframe with the results. can be used for evaluation
results = pipeline_trained.transform(df) # split the data here and use test set
```